# Add popup JTextarea to each column title in JTable

Tags: java

I am trying to make a JTable with popup help menus for each column section.  For instance, you right click on the first column title and a JTextArea pops up that explains what the column is for and what type of data should be put into it.  I have the following code establishing the JTable and the mouselistener event.  Is there a way I can write an If statement using ColumnAtPoint() so that if the right click happens at Column 1, then it opens up my JTextArea? Then I can create a second and third separate JTextAreas for my other columns.

final DefaultTableModel tblModel = new DefaultTableModel(null, colHdrs);

```
  final JTable table = new JTable(tblModel);
```

table.getTableHeader().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

```
      @Override

      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
          if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(e))
          {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textArea1, "Type", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
          }
      }   
  });
```

Comment: Why do y need a JTextArea to popup? A Tooltip would be more efficient, easier and supports HTML formatting

Answer (score 2):

Try to use JToolTip I think it might be much more suited for your use ;) :)!

You can also add e.g. to a

> JLabel label = new JLabel("My Number Label");

a tooltip text like :

> label.setToolTipText("Only Numbers From 1-10 are allowed!");

This is also possible for other swing stuff, you can try it :).
The text will appear as soon as you hover over the label .

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I thought about using JToolTip but I want the users to be able to copy/paste the text, which a mouse-hover-over pop up doesn't allow.